# Xubuntu 11.10 won't save my settings

Tags: touchpad, xubuntu, browser, default-browser

I am using Xubuntu 11.10, and every time i reboot my computer, my settings are erased.

Namely my default Browser, Preferred Applications settings and my Touchpad settings.

Does anyone know how to make these settings permanent? Tap-To-Click is super annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Upon resuming from suspend gsynaptics-init needs to be run for each open X session, I've written a script to put in /etc/pm/sleep.d/98gsynaptics to do that automatically.

This may also effect the xsession in YOUR /home folder

consult [Ubuntu Documention](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad/PreMaverick) for detailed information as to your settings.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Only run on resume/thaw
if [[ ${1} =~ (thaw|resume) ]] ; then

  synaptics() {

    # sleep to give time for X
    sleep 4s

    who | while read line ; do
      a=(${line})
      regex="^:[[:digit:]]"
      if [[ ${a[1]} =~ $regex ]] ; then
        init="sudo -H -u ${a[0]} DISPLAY=${a[1]} gsynaptics-init"
        eval "${init}"
      fi
    done
  }

  # run in background so sleep doesn't hold up resume
  synaptics &
  # disown so exiting shell doesn't kill function
  disown %1

fi
```